# SwiftUI shows white canvas after REST API connection

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swiftui, mvvm

I have connected api and it seems to be connected fine as I can see the data in console. But when I use the fields in UI nothing shows up on screen just plain white screen. No UI components are showing on screen. Swift newbie here.

Please look into it.

I have tried .onAppear as well

```
import SwiftUI

struct Carousel: View {
    
    //let categoryName: String
   // @StateObject private var envObj = EnvObj()
    @StateObject private var viewModel = EventsViewModel()
    var body: some View {
      
        
        VStack {
         ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 150) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.events.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            let scale = getScale(proxy: proxy)
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: EventDetail(),
label: {
    ZStack {
        Image(viewModel.events[index].image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 360.26)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(x:-10)
//            .overlay(
//                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
//                    .stroke(Color(white: 0.4))
//            )
//            .shadow(radius: 3)


        VStack{
        HStack(spacing: 15){

            Image("DP")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame (width: 30.57, height: 30.57)
                .clipShape (Circle ())


            Text ("James B.")
                .font(.system(size: 17))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .offset(x: -94.5 , y: -100 )

        VStack{
            HStack(spacing: -50){

                VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5) {

                    Text(viewModel.events[index].title)
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .font(.system(size: 17,weight: .medium, design: .default))


                    HStack(spacing: -20) {
                        Image("Icon material-location-on")
                        // .offset(x:2)
                        Text("McLean Hall")
                            .frame(width: 130)
                            .font(.system(size: 17))
                            .offset(x:5)
                        // .bold()
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.top)


                }
                .padding(.horizontal)

                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: -18){

                    HStack(spacing: -19){
                        Image("calender")
                            .offset(y:-25)
                        Text("Tue, 28 Feb")
                            .offset(y:-25)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .frame(width: 130)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .offset(x:10)
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    Text("10:00 PM")
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .offset(x:9,y: -getReact().height/135)
                        .frame(width: 130)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .bold()


                    // .foregroundColor(.white)
                    HStack(spacing: -29){
                        Text("From")
                            .font(.system(size: 9,weight: .regular, design: .default))
                            .frame(width: 30)
                        Text("$12.50")
                            .font(.system(size: 20,weight: .regular, design: .default))
                            .frame(width: 130)
                            .padding(.trailing,19)
                    }
                    .offset(x:20,y: getReact().height/45)

                }
                .padding(.leading,50)
            }//hstack
            .foregroundColor(.white)

        }

        .background(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).opacity(0.20)
                .frame(width: 295,height: 110)
                .cornerRadius(15)


        )
        .padding(.top)
        .offset(x:-10,y:96)
    }//vs



    }//zstack

     }//label
  )//navigation link

    .scaleEffect(.init(width: scale, height: scale))
    //.animation(.spring(), value: 1)
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1))

    .padding(.vertical)
} //End Geometry
    .frame(width: 125, height: 400)
    .padding(.horizontal, 32)
    .padding(.vertical, 32)
} //End ForEach
Spacer()
    .frame(width: 16)
} //End HStack
}// End ScrollView
}//End VStack
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchEvents)
//        .frame(width: 125, height: 400)
//        .offset(x: 15,y: 200)
       // .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        //.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
}

func getScale(proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
    let midPoint: CGFloat = 125
    
    let viewFrame = proxy.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
    
    var scale: CGFloat = 0.95
    let deltaXAnimationThreshold: CGFloat = 130
    
    let diffFromCenter = abs(midPoint - viewFrame.origin.x - deltaXAnimationThreshold / 2)
    if diffFromCenter < deltaXAnimationThreshold {
        scale = 1 + (deltaXAnimationThreshold - diffFromCenter) / 500
}
    
    return scale
}
}

struct Carousel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Carousel()
    }
}
```

here's my model view for the above corousal view

```
struct EventBase : Codable {
   
    let success : Bool
    let data : [UserResponse2]
    let message : String
}

struct UserResponse2: Codable {
    let events : [Events]
   
}

struct Events : Identifiable, Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let user_id : String?
    let category_id : String?
    let title : String
    let image : String
    let address : String?
    let city : String?
    let state : String?
    let status : String?
    let country : String?
    let zipcode : String?
    let latitude : String?
    let longitude : String?
    let start_date : String?
    let end_date : String?
    let end_time : String?
    let event_type : String?
    let description : String?
    let qr_image : String?
    let deleted_at : String?
    let created_at : String?
    let updated_at : String?
    let start_time : String?
    let tickets : [String]?
    let user : User?
    let category : Category?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case id = "id"
        case user_id = "user_id"
        case category_id = "category_id"
        case title = "title"
        case image = "image"
        case address = "address"
        case city = "city"
        case state = "state"
        case status = "status"
        case country = "country"
        case zipcode = "zipcode"
        case latitude = "latitude"
        case longitude = "longitude"
        case start_date = "start_date"
        case end_date = "end_date"
        case end_time = "end_time"
        case event_type = "event_type"
        case description = "description"
        case qr_image = "qr_image"
        case deleted_at = "deleted_at"
        case created_at = "created_at"
        case updated_at = "updated_at"
        case start_time = "start_time"
        case tickets = "tickets"
        case user = "user"
        case category = "category"
    }
}

struct Category : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let image : String?
    let deleted_at : String?
    let created_at : String?
    let updated_at : String?
    
}
```

here's my view model

```
class EventsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var events: [Events] = []
    
    
    func fetchEvents() {
        let apiRequest = ApiManager<EventBase>(successHandler: { response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard response.success,
                      let eventsData = response.data.first
                else { return }
                self.events = eventsData.events
            }
        }, nullDataSuccessHandler: { (httpStatusCode: HttpStatusCode) in
            // handle UI for null data
        }, errorHandler: { (httpStatusCode, errorMessage) in
            // handle UI for API error
        })
        apiRequest.makeNetworkCall(for: .featuredEvents, requestType: .get)
       
    }
    
}//class
```

Comment: What do you see in the console, json or your decoded data or…?

Comment: please check this link , I couldn't post whole response here so I have pasted in this link and let me know if any questions, please check last line too.  Appreciate your help, please help me I'm stuck for days thank you :))) https://pastebin.com/CwUYG7Ti

Comment: Your json doesn’t match your model so you get a decoding error.

Comment: I Checked with structure of response and the model it matches almost but you are right there's error "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead". Can you help where I can make changes I cannot find what and where to correct. Appreciate your help :))

Comment: Share the full error message.

Comment: You should include relevant parts of the json and the error message in your question.

Comment: Just for info, for json decoding error, do not print error.localizedDescription, better print error of the try/catch

Comment: This is in the console and I’ve pasted whole console response in the link I provided above. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: `let tickets : [String]?` Tickets isn't a `[String]`, that's what's saying your error.